# Jquery dynamically change data value for ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need this function to calculate every time the last id of message inserted, but this way it doesn't work, it always post the initial number

```
 $("#conversazione").smartupdater({
 url : "localhost/social/public/async/check-conversazione",
 minTimeout: 2000,
 type: 'POST',
 data: { 
    'id': id,
    'last': $(".messaggioAltri:first").attr("data-number-message")
},
dataType: 'JSON'
},
function (data) {

    if(data.aggiornamenti==1){

        $.each(data.messaggi, function(indice, message){

                       mess="<div class='singoloMessaggio'> data-number-message="+message.number+">"
                                ....
                                "</div>";

                        $(mess).hide();
                        $(mess).css({'background-color': '#FF7519'});
                        $('#messaggiConversazione').prepend(mess);
                        $(mess).fadeIn(1000);
                        $(mess).removeAttr("style");                           
                   });


    }else{
        //nothing
    }

}
);
```

i also tried to use a function instead, something like:

```
$("#conversazione").smartupdater({
 url : "localhost/social/public/async/check-conversazione",
 minTimeout: 2000,
 type: 'POST',
 data: { 
   'id': id,
   'last': getLast()
 },....etc...

function getLast(){
 return $(".messaggioAltri:first").attr("data-numero-messaggio");
}
```

But i always have the same error, with fierbug i see that it always send the initial numbers...it seems to be soo simple but i cannot figure out what's wrong...What do you suggest to do?

Comment: smartupdater() probably gets the value when first initialized, and to change that behaviour to get the value for each call, you probably have to change the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.stringify

```
$("#conversazione").smartupdater({
 url : "localhost/social/public/async/check-conversazione",
 minTimeout: 2000,
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify({'id':id,'last': getLast()}), ....etc...
});
```

Comment: Still the same error... do you also think that i should change the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `id`, so it always has the same value.

You should change its value in the callback function, something like

```
if(data.aggiornamenti==1){
     //I'm assuming the latest update is the last in the array
    id = data.aggiornamenti[data.aggiornamenti.length -1].id;
}
```

Comment: data.aggiornamenti is a simple boolean used which contains 1 if there are some new messages and 0 if not. New messages are saved in a different variable, it is in data.messages, i tried doing:
    ultimo=data.messaggi[data.messaggi.length-1];
    lastMessageId=ultimo.numero;
but i had the same problem...